# Polling for changes generates duplicate results in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a list of responses to a question.

Each response has its own timestamp converted to a integer (via `to_i`) in a `data-timestamp` attribute in the HTML.

I pull the `data-timestamp` value from the most recent response and then pass this to the controller to query the database every 5 seconds for any new responses.

The problem is that it keeps returning the last response. Repeatedly (i.e. it never stops).

I've tracked this down to the fact that when I convert the `created_at` from the database (which is in datetime format) into a integer and then back into a time object in Rails it cuts off the milliseconds i.e:

The actual timestamp of the last response:

```
2013-01-07 14:30:00.610491
```

The figure that Rails is using to query the database:

```
2013-01-07 14:30:00.000000
```

Any ideas on how I can solve this?

**EDIT: As request here's my code:**

This is what I use to grab the latest timestamp from the last response:

```
<div class="row response" data-time="<%= @response.created_at.to_i %>">
```

I then pass this as a parameter via Javascript to the controller (the responses are in reverse chronological order hence the most recent responses is first):

```
function updateResponses() {
    var after = $('.response:first').attr('data-time');
    $.getScript("/responses/polling.js?after=" + after);
}
```

In the controller I then query for all responses created after this date:

```
def polling
  @responses = Response.where("created_at > ?", Time.at(params[:after].to_i))
end
```

Comment: Show how you did "convert the created_at from the database (which is in datetime format) into a integer and then back into a time object in Rails it cuts off the milliseconds "

Comment: Does your database support millisecond precision for its datetime type?

Comment: Updated the post to show code.

Yes, database (postgres) supports millisecond precision for datetime.

Answer (score 1):

I have used

```
@latest = YOURMODEL.where("created_at > ?", Time.at(params[:after].to_i + 1))
```

with success in the past when polling for changes in rails.

Sorry can't be of anymore help without seeing more of your code

Comment: I had considered this but thought it might cause problems when two responses where posted within a second of each other. Would it not overlook the second post?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I managed to resolve this by the following:

I altered the div class so that it output the time with milliseconds as an integer

```
<div class="row response" data-time="<%= @response.created_at.utc.strftime("%s%6N").to_i %>">
```

(note the conversion UTC - important to prevent Rails from giving you a value that corresponds to the timezone you've set for the app. All datetimes are saved in the DB as UTC by default.)

I then converted this to a BigDecimal in the controller and divided to give me the correct precision on the decimal. I then used this figure to set the Time.at:

```
def polling
    undivided_millisecond_epoch_time_in_integer = params[:after]
    undivided_millisecond_epoch_time_in_decimal = (undivided_millisecond_epoch_time_in_integer).to_d
    divided_millisecond_epoch_time_in_decimal = (undivided_millisecond_epoch_time_in_decimal / 1000000).to_d
    @responses = Response.where("created_at > ?", Time.at(divided_millisecond_epoch_time_in_decimal))
end
```

This gives me the correct query with milliseconds:

```
Response Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "responses".* FROM "responses" WHERE ( created_at > '2013-01-08 08:49:28.832908')
```